# How to fetch a single data with sql in java NetBeans

Tags: java, sql

So i am trying to fetch quantity into a single variable from which i can change it and update it into the final value which is provided by the user.
The statement i am using:

```
int s= sta.executeUpdate("UPDATE stockDB SET Quantity="+quantity+" WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

So this statement updates the whole quantity data but i want to remove the quantity provided by the user not the whole quantity itself.
What statement should i add to fetch the quantity and then update it,
I tried:

```
int s= sta.executeUpdate("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
      int quan=s;
      quan=quan-quantity;
int ss= sta.executeUpdate("UPDATE stockDB SET Quantity="+quan+" WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

I am getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No row count was produced

What to do?
I know i am not doing it right.

UPDATE:

```
ResultSet rs =sta.executeQuery("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
      String str = rs.getString("Quantity");
        int quan = Integer.parseInt(str);

     int fquan;
      fquan=quan-quantity;


      int ss= sta.executeUpdate("UPDATE stockDB SET Quantity="+fquan+" WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

ERROR:

> error: Invalid cursor state

NOTE:

the quantity variable in the fquan=quan-quantity is correct.
the quantity is a variable name.

Comment: Have you tried `name = "'; DROP TABLE stockDB; --";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [executeQuery()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) for select queries.For insertion,deletion and update [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) is used and it return int.So

```
 int s= sta.executeUpdate("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

is completely wrong

`executeQuery()` returns `ResultSet` hence do like this

```
ResultSet rs =sta.executeQuery("SELECT Quantity FROM stockDB WHERE Name='"+name+"' AND Size="+size+"");
```

**Edit**

From the comments

to retrive

```
while(rs.next())
{
System.out.println(rs.getString("Quantity"));

}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to store the quantity fetched by the sql statement into a integer variable?

Comment: So ResultSet rs will store the quantity itself? if yes how to convert the rs into integer variable?

Comment: See my update i have edited the lines now i get the error: Invalid cursor state

Comment: I have anwered your question as per your original question.My answer will be invalid because you have edited your question.Instead you should post another question

Comment: alright thank you your answer helped me to get something new.